# iOS issue in login screen: signupActionButton is not showing valid result

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn swift, my "SignupButtonAction" is not redirecting to signup screen, please help. Thank you in advance

import UIKit

class Login: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailID: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

// Hitting Signup screen

```
@IBAction func SignupButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let Signup = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Signup")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Signup, animated: true)
    
}
```

//Login button action

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    let emailID = emailID.text;
    let password = password.text;
    
    
    
    //check for empty fields
    if (emailID?.isEmpty ?? true || password?.isEmpty ?? true) {
        
        // diplay alert message
       displayalert(usermessage: "All fields are required");
        return;
    }
    
    
    // store data
    
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(emailID, forKey: "emailID");
    UserDefaults.standard.set(password, forKey: "password");
    
    // display alert message with confirmation
    
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Login successful, Thank you!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert);
    
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { action in
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let dashboard = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Dashboard")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

// displaying error alert
func displayalert(usermessage: String){
let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: usermessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert);

```
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok",style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil);
        
        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
        
    }
```

}

Comment: Check if you have `self.navigationController?` is not nil.

Comment: can you please explain a little more, how can I check this?

Comment: JUst Make a breakpoint at line above in mentioned and in console print `self.navigationController?`

Comment: okay checking thank you for your help :)

Comment: In general, folks here will expect that you have done the basic debugging steps into your own code. SO is a terrible debugger.